# why other peoples facebook events not showing into my android app when they login to my app

Tags: java, android, json, facebook-graph-api

I am building an android app, which is integrated with Facebook graph API for user_events. When i login to my app, my events are showing up, but whenever other user logged in to my app - no events are showing.
When i tried to debug the app, its showing "JSON data null".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to send in `user_events` for [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review). Without Review, it only works for users with a role in the App. There should actually be a warning about this when you login as App Admin.